# Save Multiple Metabox values

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox

How to Save Multiple Metabox values ?

I have 3 fields like below image.

[image]

Should I use below code ?

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']));
}

if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'address', sanitize_text_field($_POST['address']));
}

if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field($_POST['phone']));
}
```

Is there any way to Save multiple metabox values ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the way you should save. However, if the, let's say, `$_POST['name'] ` is not set, the meta field `name` won't be created and if you need to use it for Query, you won't get desired results. Better you save an empty value if `$_POST['name'] ` is not set. That's my own opinion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where this code exists, if it's in a callback of a ajax or post event but it doesn't really matter.

Assuming your code works as expected you could make it a bit easier to manage, lets say you have another 7 meta fields you need to update, you'll need to copy paste your if conditions every time which is not ideal.

PHP also has a built in function for dealing with requests, `filter_input`, this function allows you to sanitize and validate the request data exactly as you need it, there are many flag for data types and common values like email.

So you could do something like this

```php
$fields = [
    'name'    => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'address' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'phone'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
];

foreach ($fields as $field_name => $flag) {
    if (!empty($field = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $field_name, $flag))) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $field_name, sanitize_text_field($field));
    }
}
```

So now if you need to add another field, lets say `email`, you can just update the `$field` array instead of creating a new condition.
This

```php
$fields = [
    'name'    => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'address' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'phone'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
    'email'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
];
```

Instead of another

```php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Buttered_Toast. Actually I am learning Plugin Development. I have Custom Post `News`. I would like to save some other values with this Custom Post.  In this case I am using Metaboxes. I don't know whether is it proper way. I have to save almost 40 other values. You can check this screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgWah.png

Comment: You have events you can hook into on `save`, the wordpress plugin development handbooks goes over that as well. Using my method at least you wont need to create 40+ `if` conditions =D

Comment: Thanks @Buttered_Toast. I know there is a `save` hook. But am I in right way ? Is it the proper way to develop a plugin ? Thanks.

Comment: With the minimal code you provided I can say for sure because I don't know what the plugin is about, what I know so far is that you have a POST request and you want yo update meta data based on that request, the way you did it is correct, using `sanitize_text_field` before saving the data is really good and appropriate, you can make your code more maintainable as I showed. With the code you provided so far you're doing fine. continue reading the wordpress plugin development handbook and you'll be fine

Comment: Thanks @Buttered_Toast. Did you check this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207368/constant-filter-sanitize-string-is-deprecated